# Change ylab position in R Scatterplot3D

Tags: r, position, scatter-plot

I´m working with R scatterplot3D and I need to use expression() in labels because I have to use some Greek letters;
my question is: is there a way to pull the y.lab name down or write it along the axis (in a diagonal position)? I went to help and packages description but nothing seems to work;
thanks in advance for any help
Maria

```
library(scatterplot3d)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
A <- c(3,2,3,3,2)
B <- c(2,4,5,3,4)
D <- c(4,3,4,2,3)
scatterplot3d(A,D,B, xlab=expression(paste(x[a],"-",x[b])), 
                     ylab=expression(x[a]), 
                     zlab=expression(sigma^2))
```

Comment: That's not possible due to the way scatterplot3d is constructed. Very interesting question nonetheless!

Comment: I would just switch off the axis labels (`xlab=""`) all together and use `mtext()`. Does that work?

Comment: Although I'm not really satisfied, you could it manually with something like `text(x = 16.5, y = 4.5, expression(x[a]), xpd = T, srt = 60)`. I called `axis(1)` and `axis(2)` to find a possible location for the text "by eye".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use any of the classic ways due to the way the `scatterplot3d()` function constructs the plot. It's basically plotted on top of a classic plot pane, which means the axis labels are bound to the classic positions. The z-label is printed at the real left Y-axis, and the y label is printed at the real right Y-axis.

You can use `text()` to get around this:

- use `par("usr")` to get the limits of the X and Y coordinates
- calculate the position you want the label on (at 90% of the horizontal position and 8% of the vertical position for example.)
- use `text()` to place it (and possibly the parameter `srt` to turn the label)

This makes it a bit more generic, so you don't have try different values for every new plot you make.

Example :

```
scatterplot3d(A,D,B, xlab=expression(paste(x[a],"-",x[b])),
                     ylab="",
                     zlab=expression(sigma^2))
dims <- par("usr")
x <- dims[1]+ 0.9*diff(dims[1:2])
y <- dims[3]+ 0.08*diff(dims[3:4])
text(x,y,expression(x[a]),srt=45)
```

Gives

[image]

Comment: Excellent illustration of programmatic access to base-graphics parameter information.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments! This solution it´s really what I was looking for (in fact now that I see it, we can also let the option srt=45 out because ylab name stays aligned with the y values axis and perhaps that way we can read it better) Maria D.

Comment: @MariaD If you don't need `srt`, using `mtext` would be the preferred way for me.

Comment: @MariaD PS: If any of the answers helped you, feel free to give them a vote and to accept one by clicking on the V left of that answer. For more information on how the site works, check [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

```
scatterplot3d(A,D,B, xlab=expression(paste(x[a],"-",x[b])), 
                      ylab="", 
                      zlab=expression(sigma^2))
mtext( expression(x[a]), side=4,las=2,padj=18, line=-4)
```

One does need to use fairly extreme parameter values to get the expression in the right place in that transformed spatial projection.

Comment: Or use mtext indeed, but mtext doesn't react on `srt` afaik

Comment: I thought your use of text was superior because `mtext` does not allow any rotations except integral multiples of 90.