# Rotate y-axis label in scatterplot3d (adjust to angle of axis)

Tags: r, plot, 3d, rotation, visualization

I use `scatterplot3d` to plot 3D with R. The orientation of the y-axis label bothers me because it is vertical and not parallel to the y-axis.
Is there a way to rotate the label and adjust its angle? Unfortunately, I didn't finde anything in the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scatterplot3d/scatterplot3d.pdf).

Comment: Is [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458652/specifying-the-orientation-of-the-axes-labels-in-scatterplot3d) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to draw many plots and are willing to adjust values manually, you can pass `ylab = ""` when making the 3d scatter and then add `text` later on with appropriate `srt` value. `srt` allows you to rotate text at desired angle. Note that `x` and `y` when adding text is different from `x` and `y` of 3d scatter.

```
set.seed(42)
scatterplot3d(rnorm(20), rnorm(20), rnorm(20), ylab = "")
text(x = 5, y = -2.5, "Y-axis", srt = 45)
```

[image]

**Using `scale.y`**

```
set.seed(42)
scatterplot3d(rnorm(20), rnorm(20), rnorm(20), ylab = "", scale.y = 2)
text(x = 6.5, y = -1.5, "Somewhat longer Y-axis", srt = 45)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have been doing now! I guess that's the easiest way, considering that I only have one plot.

Comment: Also I have the problem that the problem that the text is cut off at the right even though the margin is large enough and there is just white space. If I move it further down/left, it gets cut off there...

Comment: What's `scale.y` and how to use it? I couldn't find anything on it on Google.