# Position of title of ylab in scatterplot3d in R

Tags: r

I try to plot 3D scatter plot and I am using `scatterplot3d`. The ylab title is too far in end of the right side it is not close to the plot.

```
require(scatterplot3d)
require(plotrix)
with(wc, {
 s3d <- scatterplot3d(W, G, C,  # x y and z axis
 color = "blue", pch = 19,
 type = "h",
 main = "3-D Scatterplot",
 xlab = "W",
 ylab = "G",
 zlab = "C")
})
```

How to change the position of ylab title?

I try suggestion as @pascal proposed. But I stumble upon error
 `Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. As it is solved in this link 
[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637484/change-ylab-position-in-r-scatterplot3d)!

Could you explain me what is the role of this part of the script.

```
dims <- ("usr")
x <- dims[1]+ 0.9*diff(dims[1:2])
y <- dims[3]+ 0.08*diff(dims[3:4])  
text(x,y,expression(),srt=45)
```

Thanks guys for the help I find the mistake in my code. I really appreciate your help. Special thanks to @Pascal.

Comment: What is object `wc`? Without it, your example is not reproducible.

Comment: `wc` is a dataframe that I subset for 3 variables and after that I plot them. The problem that I face is that `ylab = "G"` title is in the extreme right on the plot.

Comment: Sure, but you are asked to provide a minimal, reproducible example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change ylab position in R Scatterplot3D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637484/change-ylab-position-in-r-scatterplot3d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick search and found a thread with the exact same problem and a solution: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637484/change-ylab-position-in-r-scatterplot3d).

Comment: I try your suggestion but I face an error `Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator`. What is the problem?